# Error - Cannot read property 'value' of null

Tags: javascript, html

I have seen multiple articles about this problem, which I hadn't experienced until now.

I have an input field with the id "fname" and want to get the element by id and store its value in a variable.

However, I keep getting the error mentioned in the title.

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
var lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<p>Enter the first string:<input type = "name" id="fname">
<p>Enter the second:<input type = "name" id="lname"></p>
```

Anyone able to fetch the error? I have been trying for the past 20 minutes.

Comment: Is the script running before the DOM is ready?

Comment: Is this javascript running before the elements are actually in the DOM, perchance..?

Comment: The script is executed immediately. Even if you move it below those `<input>`s, both values will be `""`.

Comment: ...about what? What's the next step here? If you want to do something with `fname` and `lname`, you need to run that code after the user has entered something. For instance in a button's click listener. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/h5mr78ez/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should always load the scripts after the DOM element. In this case, you should move the script to the bottom to make it work. It is always prefered way to load the script just before body end tag `</body/>`

```
<p>Enter the first string:<input type = "name" id="fname">
<p>Enter the second:<input type = "name" id="lname"></p>

<script>
var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
var lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
</script>
```

Live running example - https://jsitor.com/Rg0jU9HFN

Comment: Great, thank you, I made a button onclick starts the script. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Thanks, if this solution is working for you, you can mark it resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You need the execute the Javascript code after the document has fully rendered. 
Javascript has built-in feature for this, no need to trigger it on button.

```
<p>Enter the first string:<input type = "name" id="fname">
<p>Enter the second:<input type = "name" id="lname"></p>

<script>
//first define the variables so they are available in the global scope
var fname, lname;

//once the document has fully loaded, call the function 
//passed as second argument to the addEventListener method
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ 
   fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
   lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
});
</script>
```

Note that it won't work in older Internet Explorer versions, as they don't support the DOMContentLoaded event.